# Android BluetoothLE Pripheral

Tags: android

http://qiita.com/anzai_k/items/131373caa0a6294efdd4

上記のサイトを参考にBLE Peripheralアプリを作成しました。
しかし、CentralからReadRequestが来ると下記のエラーを出力してサービスをクリアしてしまいます。調べても解決できなかったため質問させていただきます。

```
W/BluetoothGattServer: Unhandled exception in callback

java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'boolean android.bluetooth.BluetoothGattServer.sendResponse(android.bluetooth.BluetoothDevice, int, int, int, byte[])' on a null object reference
```

Answer (score 1):

作成されているアプリのコードが記載されていないため、参考にされているサイトのコードからの推測です。

### まずは直接の原因から

以下のAPIをコールしようとして`java.lang.NullPointerException`が発生しています。

> android.bluetooth.BluetoothGattServer.sendResponse

### 原因の理由を考える

ReadRequestが来た時ということなので以下のコードで発生しているのでしょう。

```
//セントラル（クライアント）からReadRequestが来ると呼ばれる
@TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN_MR2)
public void onCharacteristicReadRequest(android.bluetooth.BluetoothDevice device, int requestId, 
    int offset, BluetoothGattCharacteristic characteristic) {
(略)
    bluetoothGattServer.sendResponse(device, requestId, BluetoothGatt.GATT_SUCCESS, offset,
(略)
}
```

つまり`bluetoothGattServer`が`null`であることが原因です。
次に`bluetoothGattServer`を見ていきます。
すると以下のコンストラクタで代入されていることがわかります。

```
//BLE
private BluetoothGattServer bluetoothGattServer;
public BLEServer(BluetoothGattServer gattServer) {
    this.bluetoothGattServer = gattServer;
}
```

おそらくコンストラクタに渡されている`gattServer`が`null`なのだと考えられます。
次にこの`BELServer`をインスタンス化しているところを探します。
すると以下の処理で`BLEServer`をインスタンス化しているようです。

```
//GattServerを取得
@TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN_MR2)
private BluetoothGattServer getGattServer(Context context, BluetoothManager manager) {
    return manager.openGattServer(context, new BLEServer(gattServer));
}
```

ここで渡されている`gattServer`を探します。宣言はメンバ変数ですね。

```
private BluetoothGattServer gattServer;
```

ここで`gattSever`に代入しているみたいです。

```
//アドバタイズを開始
@TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP)
public void startAdvertise(Context context) {

    //BLE各種を取得
    BluetoothManager manager = (BluetoothManager) context.getSystemService(Context.BLUETOOTH_SERVICE);
    BluetoothAdapter adapter = manager.getAdapter();
    advertiser = getAdvertiser(adapter);
    gattServer = getGattServer(context, manager);
(略)
}
```

ここまで調べておかしいことに気づいてください。
`gattServer`に代入するために呼び出しているメソッドが先ほど`BLEServer`をインスタンス化しようとしていた`getGattServer`メソッドになっています。
つまり`getGattServer`メソッドを呼び出している段階では、`gattServer`はインスタンス化されていません。（=null）
そのため`BLEServer`のコンストラクタに渡されている`gattServer`は`null`になっていると考えられます。

あとはご自身のコードをデバッグしてみて実際にどこが`null`なのかを調査してみてください。